# What is the syntax error in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a piece of code that I am trying to fix. What is the syntax that is causing this error. What do I need to do to fix it?

Here is the error I'm getting:

> SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="/shared/JSApps/jQuery/v1.7/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>');
    //]]>
    </script>
```

Comment: SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'

Comment: What is the purpose using `||` ? , `document.write()` ? Is jquery loaded into document before `<script>` at Question ?

Comment: George, make sure to ALWAYS include the error in the post please. It make it easier for us to help.

Comment: Are you sure you placing the `script` tag correctly? The code does not cause such an error, maybe this is a JavaScript file? If so you don't need script tags.

Comment: @GeorgeMurphy See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805800/why-does-a-script-work-in-firebugs-command-line-on-one-site-but-not-on-another

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any issues with the snippet you've posted. Does the request to `/shared/JSApps/jQuery/v1.7/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` succeed? If it's receiving a 404, for example, is the server responding with an error page?

Comment: @guest271314 The pattern can be used with a CDN, such as [code.jquery.com](http://code.jquery.com/), to have a fallback. If the CDN is available, you benefit from its caching; if it's unavailable, the local script is used instead via `document.write()`. [Reference](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CDNsFailButYourScriptsDontHaveToFallbackFromCDNToLocalJQuery.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Check your network tab. I would almost guarantee that `/shared/JSApps/jQuery/v1.7/jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is returning an HTML document instead of your script.

Dev Tools > Network > jquery-1.7.1.min.js > preview tab.

Comment: Like asked above, where is your snippet located? In HTML?

Comment: It is in the head of the document first JS file

Comment: Check your network tab like this: http://i.imgur.com/4pTrsQp.png See what the preview shows in your jQuery request, or if the jQuery request is even happening. If the jQuery request isn't happening could you share your <head>?