# load jquery after page initialization using javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a project to provide facebook autentication to an existing captive portal. This captive portal has one option to customize the template so... I can edit the html code to show one of my own.

The problem is that for some reason every time I import a script on the template like this

```
<script src="external http or https script"></script>
```

it fails and the result is a blank page with nothing loaded from the template...

I had found a solution by importing the script after the page has loaded like this....

```
var script=document.createElement('script');
script.src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
head.appendChild(script);
```

It is working ... I can confirm on console that calling $('body') for example return the body element of html.. so jquery is ready...

My problem:
If, after loading jquery ussing the workaraound I load other scripts (angular and socket.io in this case) those scripts fail with jquery issues

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

My question: 
How can i do to load those scripts after the jquery has finish loaded...
Do I need to initialize jquery some how to use it?

Thanks in advance

FULL CODE

```
 <html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="-1"/>
</head>
<body onload="initialFunction()">
<script>
function initialFunction(){
    document.getElementsByName('username')[0].placeholder="Nombre de Usuario"
    document.getElementsByName('password')[0].placeholder="Contraseña"
    var script=document.createElement('script');
    var angularScript=document.createElement('script');
    var socketScript=document.createElement('script');
    var angularFacebookScript=document.createElement('script');
    var appScript=document.createElement('script');
    var materializeScript=document.createElement('script');
    script.src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js";
    angularScript.src="http://192.168.1.5/js/angular.js";
    socketScript.src="http://192.168.1.5:8080/socket.io/socket.io.js"
    angularFacebookScript.src="http://192.168.1.5/angular-facebook-master/lib/angular-facebook.js"
    appScript.src="http://192.168.1.5/js/app.js"
    materializeScript.src="http://192.168.1.5/js/materialize.min.js"
    var head=document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]
    var body=document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
    head.appendChild(script);
    body.appendChild(angularScript);
    body.appendChild(socketScript);
    body.appendChild(angularFacebookScript);
    body.appendChild(appScript);
    body.appendChild(materializeScript);
}
</script>
<center>
    <style>
        body {
        background-color:#298eea;
        }
        ....some other stuff...
    </style>
    <div>
        <h3>{company_logo}</h3>
        <h2>Captive Portal</h2>
        <div id="__loginbox"></div> 
        //here I want to insert the facebook button with an angular controller to pass info to a backend via socket io.... I have already do that before ussing the "normal way"
    </div>
</center>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you show whole code for your index html file? The normal way of including via `<script>` tag, and not the JS workaround. I want to see the order of importing.

Comment: You could use  `onload` event at `script` variable to perform same tasks; that is; when jquery is loaded create addtional `script` elements, use `onload` event at those `script` elements

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29805800/why-does-a-script-work-in-firebugs-command-line-on-one-site-but-not-on-another

Comment: full code posted... question edited

Comment: @ArielWeinberger thanks for your comments.. I have tryied the normal way before :D... unfurtunatelly dont know why the result is that the captive portal breaks and show only an emty body tag... ussing the workarround it does not break

Comment: **NOTE** that you [_should **not** use_](http://blog.jquery.com/2014/07/03/dont-use-jquery-latest-js/) `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`

Comment: Noted thanks I am locally downloading it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `onload` event at `script` variables

```
script.onload = function() {
  console.log(jQuery().jquery);
  // do stuff with jQuery script
}

angularScript.onload = function() {
  // do stuff with angular script
}
```

similarly with `socketScript`, `angularFacebookScript`, `appScript`, `materializeScript`

Comment: excelent :D just loaded all jquery dependant functions inside the onload metod of script... great thanks a lot...